# Discord Python - How to make the BOT search for a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Does anyone know how to make the bot look for a specific message in a specific channel on a specific server? If the bot has found it, he will do something, otherwise he would do something else.

I have this for now :

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def command(ctx):
    search = discord.utils.get(bot.get_message, message = 'MESSAGE', channel = bot.get_channel(id = 'CHANNEL ID'))
    if search is not None:
        await bot.say("Something")
    else:
        await bot.say("Something else")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use [`logs_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) to read through the messages of channel with the ids, looking for a message that contains the id of the server the command was invoked in.

```
from discord import NotFound

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="command")
async def _command(ctx):
    channel_id = "123"
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    if not channel:
        await bot.say("Error: Could not resolve controller channel")
        return
    server_id = ctx.message.server.id
    async for message in bot.logs_from(channel, limit=500):
        if server_id in message.content:
            await bot.say("SSM")
            return
    await bot.say("SSM ELSE")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do then.  What message are you trying to get?  What do you know about it?

Comment: Could you store the server IDs somewhere else?  It would make much more sense to just store them in a text file with your bot